# Is it possible to run the Python Camelot library on Windows Server Core?

Tags: python, docker, opencv, server-core

I am using Camelot in a Python script, which we package as an executable using pyinstaller.

This works fine on: a Windows 10 desktop, a Windows Server, even in a Docker container using mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1909.

We are trying to get this working in a Docker container just using Windows Server Core 2019 (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019) but we are getting the dreaded missing DLL problem which seems to affect some uses of OpenCV.

\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "lib\site-packages\cv2__init__.py", line 9, in 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I gather that this is because the Windows Media Feature Pack is not part of the server core, and I don't think is available as an add-on option.

Our question is this: will it be possible to run this script on Windows Server Core (plus a few other components) or do we need to run an image based on a full windows install?

Answer (score 1):

I have reached the same problem running ffmpeg on windows core. It says mfplat.dll is missing. That file is a part of Media Feature Pack, which is absent for windows core installation.

I just extracted that file from windows server 2019 full version and putted near ffmpeg.exe. It solved problem.

I guess, you can go the same way. Identify required dll files first, then just copy from full version.

Comment: thanks Andrey, I'll give that a try.  Part of the challenge will be to find exactly which DLLs are required, and also whether just putting them on the path without registering them will work.  Good that you got yours working!